# Declare array over ssh

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, ssh, declare

I try to declare an array over ssh with command:

```
 ssh root@myserver " declare -a users=( user1 user2 user3 user4 user5 ); for user in ${users[*]}; do /usr/sbin/userdel -r $user; done "
```

When I execute this command, I receive an error like:

```
sh: syntax error at line 1: `(' unexpected
```

So what is my mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: The error indicates that you're running `sh` and not `bash` on the remote server. Does that help? Hint: `sh` doesn't support arrays.

Comment: Yes. This should be the reason. So I will write a separate script and will pass to remote bash shell by:

    ssh [user]@[server] 'bash -s' < myscript.sh

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using:

```
ssh [user]@[server] 'bash -s' < myscript.sh
```